# Can you specify the return type of a method in a clojure defrecord?

Tags: methods, types, clojure

I've created an application-info interface and a class but when I review the generated classes the return type for all of the methods is Object, can I change the return type to String? The documentation says type hinting is possible with defrecord but doesn't give an example, the only examples I could find were for type hinting fields and method arguments.

src/com/vnetpublishing.clj

```
(ns com.vnetpublishing)

(defprotocol ApplicationInfo
  (author [obj])
  (author-email [obj])
  (copyright [obj])
  (app-name [obj])
  (version [obj])
)
```

src/Physics.clj

```
(ns Physics)

(defrecord info [] com.vnetpublishing.ApplicationInfo
  (author [this] "Ralph Ritoch")
  (author-email [this] "Ralph Ritoch <root@localhost>")
  (copyright [this] "Copyright \u00A9 2014 Ralph Ritoch. All rights reserved.")
  (app-name [this] "Physics")
  (version [this] "0.0.1-alpha")
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [definterface](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/definterface) macro. 
Unlike defprotocol, the definterface macro provide a way to write return type hint for methods.

Alan Malloy explain this pretty well [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/JxYHE4eqDv4):

"Protocols are for consumption by Clojure functions, which aren't
supposed to be statically typed; interfaces are for consumption by
Java classes, which are required to be statically typed."

You can then use it like:

```
(definterface Test
 (^void returnsVoid [])
 (^int returnsInt [])
 (^long returnsLong [])                                                             
 (^String returnsString [])
 (^java.util.HashMap returnsJavaUtilHashMap []))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type-hint the protocol ...

```
(defprotocol ApplicationInfo
  (author ^String [obj])
  ; ...
  )
```

but I'm told that this type-hint is probably ignored (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963889/does-hinting-return-types-in-protocols-have-any-effect-within-clojure) follow-up question).

Comment: So you are asking a question inside someone's question?