# Does hinting return types in protocols have any effect within Clojure?

Tags: clojure

You can hint a return type in a protocol

```
(defprotocol Individual
  (^Integer age [this]))
```

and the compiler will make your methods comply:

```
(defrecord person []
  Individual
  (^String age [this] "one"))

; CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched return type: age, expected: java.lang.Object, had: java.lang.String, ...
```

But you don't have to honour the type-hint:

```
(defrecord person []
  Individual
  (age [this] "one"))

(age (new person))
; "one"
```

Does the type-hint have any effect?

---

This is a follow up to [Can you specify the return type of a method in a clojure defrecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954681/can-you-specify-the-return-type-of-a-method-in-a-clojure-defrecord)

Comment: The type hints are misplaced. Should be like `(age ^String [this] "one")`. The compiler does *not* make methods comply.

Comment: Confusing, but on the method name as you had it is the correct location for the type hint in defrecord (see doc). I don't know that there is a correct place in defprotocol as non-primitive hints there seem to be ignored and primitive hints seem to break the ability to implement them. I've deleted my answer as speculative at best.

Comment: @A.Webb Thank you for your efforts. I'm inclined to leave the question as a signpost warning the bemused, myself included.

Answer (score 3):

The return type hint goes to the protocol function `age` as tag. From there, the tag is used in local type inference. To observe this in action:

`- (.longValue (age (new person)))
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
net.bendlas.lintox/eval18038 (form-init4752901931682060526.clj:1)
;; longValue is a method of Integer, so a direct cast has been inserted`

If the type hint had been left off, or if you call a method not on the hinted type, the compiler inserts a (slow) call into the reflector, instead of the plain cast:

`- (.otherMethod (age (new person)))
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: otherMethod for class java.lang.String    clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)`